# The value still store in database even the number of room is max number

Tags: php, database, mysqli

```
<?php
$sql1 = "SELECT rmType,dateCi, SUM(rmNum) as total FROM reserve GROUP BY rmType,dateCi";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
if ($row1['dateCi'] == $_SESSION['checkIn']){
if ($row1['rmType'] == 'sBed'){
    if ($row1['total'] >= 10) {
        echo "<script>alert('Single Bed Room is Full Occupied.')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "";
    }
}
if ($row1['rmType'] == 'tSBed'){
        if ($row1['total'] >= 10) {
        echo "<script>alert('Two Single Bed Room is Full Occupied'></script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "";
    }
}
if ($row1['rmType'] == 'dBed'){
        if ($row1['total'] >= 5) {
        echo "<script>alert('Double Bed Room is Full Occupied')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "";
    }
}
if ($row1['rmType'] == 'fBed'){
        if ($row1['total'] >= 12) {
        echo "<script>alert('Four-Bed Domitary Room is Full Occupied'></script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "";
    }
}
}
if ($row1['dateCi'] == $_SESSION['checkOut']){
if ($row1['rmType'] == 'sBed'){
    if ($row1['total'] >= 10) {
        echo "<script>alert('Single Bed Room is Full Occupied.')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "";
    }
}
if ($row1['rmType'] == 'tSBed'){
        if ($row1['total'] >= 10) {
        echo "<script>alert('Two Single Bed Room is Full Occupied'></script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "";
    }
}
if ($row1['rmType'] == 'dBed'){
        if ($row1['total'] >= 5) {
        echo "<script>alert('Double Bed Room is Full Occupied'></script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "";
    }
}
if ($row1['rmType'] == 'fBed'){
        if ($row1['total'] >= 12) {
        echo "<script>alert('Four-Bed Domitary Room is Full Occupied'></script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "";
    }
}
}
}
?>
<?php
$query = "INSERT INTO `reserve` (`userId`,`userName`,`userEmail`,`rmType`,`rmNum`,`guest`,`dateCi`,`dateCo`,`cost`) VALUES('".$userRow['userId']."','".$userRow['userName']."','".$userRow['userEmail']."','".$roomtype."','".$roomNum."','".$guest."','".$checkIn."','".$checkOut."','".$pay."')";         
            $res1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            if($res1) {
$update = "UPDATE users SET costPay='$pay1' WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user'];
            $run_up = mysqli_query($conn,$update);
        if($run_up){
         echo "<script>alert('This process reservation has successful.')</script>";
         echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
     }}
    else
    {
            echo "Error: " . $res . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

From the coding shown is explain about checking the room number, if it reach the max then it will echo the script that room full and open new window to homepage.
if it do not reach the max then it will store those value into table.
but the problem i met now is even the room is full, it still store those value into the table.

May someone help me please?

Comment: When you debug this, where specifically is it going wrong?  Where is this specific comparison being performed?  What are the values being compared?  Where did those values come from?  Where do you conditionally execute the database query?

Comment: as the if statement above stated, if ($row1['total'] >= 10)  then it will echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>"; it did go to index.php but at the same time,it also store the value into database which i dont want to store

Comment: It doesn't look like there's any `if` statement surrounding your database code.  So that's going to execute every time, since there's no condition being checked.

Comment: sorry for my newcomer to PHP, may i ask what should i do so that it wont be execute every time?

Comment: Your main options would be either to wrap it in an `if` statement which checks some condition (defined by you) to determine whether or not to execute that code, or to end the execution of the script before it reaches that code in the first place (with something like an `exit;` statement) which would likely happen in one (or more) of your previous `if` blocks.

Comment: it solved by adding the exit; code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are (wrongly) assuming that `echo` outputs the contents straight away in all cases.  It doesn't.  Instead it builds up a buffer to output when:

- the buffer reaches a certain size, or
- when the script stops executing, or
- when the buffer is flushed to force an output

As you build the output and don't have any controls around the insert statement, it will always hit that insert statement, which is what it is currently doing.

Fortunately there's a few ways around this:

- put an `exit;` after each block of echo'd script (that will terminate the script and cause the output to happen)
- set a variable after the `echo` parts and check for that before inserting (or not inserting)
- Change the control flow so instead of `if ... if ... if ...` you make use of `if...elseif...else`, where the `else` houses the insert statement which will then only run if none of the other conditions matched

There are other ways of doing the same action, but the up-shot is, the script will try not to output anything until it has completed, and part of that includes the insert.

Comment: so it mean i put the exit; after each of the echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>"; it can be stop the execution of INSERT if the IF condtion is fulfilled?